# How to make divs move when browser/screen is resized

Tags: html, css

I'm building a pretty basic website using a fluid design, so using percentages instead of pixel values when determining the width of the divs.

When I resize the browser or the screen size changes, the divs don't move, they just resize to the shape of the browser... so effectively when the browser changes size I want row1 to be at the top, then col1 on its own row, then col2 on its on row etc etc, I've exhausted most things, even trying to reverse engineer it from other peoples posts who want their divs to stay put, ny help would be great because this is super annoying :)

***HTML***

```
    <DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
</head>

<header>
    <div class="navbar">

    </div>
</header>

<body>
        <div class="row1">

        </div>
        <div class="row2">
            <div class="col1">

            </div>

            <div class="col2">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row3">
            <div class="col2">

            </div>

            <div class="col1">

            </div>
        </div>  
</body>


<footer>

</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
    * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.navbar {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:75px;
    background-color: #c0f4de;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

.row1 {
    margin-top:75px auto;
    background-color: #c0f4de;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
}

.row2 {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
}

.col1{
    width:50%;
    height:500px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float:left;
}

.col2 {
    width:50%;
    height:500px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The `DOCTYPE` declaration is missing a `!`. `<header>` and `<footer>` do not belong outside of the `<body>`.

Comment: Will this contribute to the issue?

Comment: @DCWD It won't but Xufox is right and it could help you to become much better web developer. Making right of your mistakes means a lot. Cheers!

Comment: You're setting the columns to 50% width so whatever size the browser, that's how they're going to behave. If you want to change the behavior based on certain browser widths you need to use responsive CSS.

Comment: Use position `relative`, or `margins` to position elements to make things fluid. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `media` query in your CSS. A `media` query is strictly for different screen sizes so it will resize appropriately. It looks like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 500px) {
    .navbar {
        width: 75%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “A `media` query is strictly for different screen sizes”. `media` queries can also distinguish screen resolution, orientation, screen shape and a lot of other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    .col1, .col2, .row1, .row2 {
        clear: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
};
```

Also, regarding what someone said about having valid code. I don't think that's the problem here. However, sometimes the browser will do unexpected things if you don't have valid code. 
W3 Schools have a validator which can check that code is valid:
https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

what you're after here are **`media queries`**.

**`Media queries`** simply load `CSS` when it hits a certain condition. A simple start would be something like this:

```
.col1 {
   width: 100%;
}
.col2 {
   width: 100%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 640px) {

 /* Code that runs when browser width is at least 640px */

{


@media all and (min-width: 1140px) {

 /* Code that runs when browser width is at least 1140px */

 .col1 {
   width: 50%;
 }
 .col2 {
   width: 50%;
 }

{
```

The `CSS` properties set later will override the previous properties. 
You can look into using `Bootstrap`'s `grid system` if this is too time consuming.